# Need help understanding this promise and handling the error

Tags: firebase, promise, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

I am saving some data into my Firebase database inside my Polymer element. All works fine. But as I person who's new to Promises I need help to understand what `Promise.resolved()` means here at then end of the method. Isn't the promise going through before that when `.then` is used? So what exactly this is doing? I looked [around](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) but can't find an example of `resolved()` with no value.

And how can I change this to have more familiar structure as below:

```
.then(function(snapshot) {
  // The Promise was "fulfilled" (it succeeded).
}, function(error) {
  // The Promise was rejected.
});
```

Here's the block and the `Promise.resolved()` taken from the [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-document#method-save):

```
saveData : function() {          
          this.$.document.data = this.$.message.value; 
          this.$.document.save("/parent", "child").then(function() {
            console.log('sent the event!!!!!!');
            this.$.document.reset();
          }.bind(this));

         return Promise.resolve();
        },
```

Comment: In addition to what you are asking, you also appear to have a scope issue. `this` in the outer and inner functions is likely to be different and `this.$.document.reset();` will likely throw.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - That's why there's a `.bind(this)`.

Comment: Whoops, senior moment!! Thanks for spotting that @jfriend00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to understand the basics of Promises.

Lets start from very basics -

A newly created es6 promise is in one of the following states:

- resolved
- rejected
- pending --> waiting to either resolved or rejected

Lets create a sample Promise

```
var promise = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
  // Do some stuff and either fullfill or reject the promise
});
```

So above promise receives a callback function also called **executor** function with signature `function(fullfill, reject)`.

A newly created promise also has a very important property function called `then` used for chaining and controlling the logic flows.

`then` takes two optional callback parameters `onFulfilled` and `onRejected`.

Inside this **executor** function two things happens to indicate the outcome of promise -

- `fullfill` **method gets called with or without a value:**

  means operation completed successfully. If you call **fulfill** with a **value** then `onFulfilled` callback in `then` will receive that value, if you decided not to provide a value in `fulfill` call then `onFulfilled` will be called with a parameter `undefined`.

  ```
  var promise = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
     // lets assume operation completed successfully
     fulfill('Success');
  });

  promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);

  function onFulfilled(result) {
       console.log(result);
       // Success will be printed
  }
  ```
- `reject` **method gets called with or without a value:**
  Some problem occurred while performing the operation. You can decided whether pass some error message `reject` callback to indicate the error occurred to end user.

  ```
  var promise = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
     // lets assume operation did not complete successfully
     reject(new Error('Error'));
  });

  promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);

  function onRejected(error) {
       console.log(error.message);
       // Error message will be printed
  }
  ```

Now lets talk about `Promise.resolve`.

At the top you learned how to create promise through the constructor.

```
var promise = new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
  fulfill('Success value');
});

// Now: Promise.resolve
// Exactly does the same thing as above code

var promise = Promise.resolve('Success value');
```

Similarly comes `Promise.reject` -

```
var promise = new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
  reject(new Error('Error VALUE'));
});

var promise = Promise.reject(new Error('Error VALUE'));
```

In your case `save` seems to be returning a promise already and internally that promise may be calling either `fulfill` or `reject` method so you don't need to call `Promise.resolve()`. You just need to get the values returned by that promise either `fulfilled` value or `rejected` value in the `then` method.

```
 saveData : function() {          
      this.$.document.data = this.$.message.value; 
      // return this promise
      return this.$.document.save("/parent", "child");
 }

saveData()
.then(function() {
        console.log('sent the event!!!!!!');
        this.$.document.reset();
      }.bind(this));
```

I hope it makes things about promises somewhat clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WitVault, I wish all the answers I get were like this :P I had suspicions about that Promise.resolved() and that it might be redundant. Interestingly it is taken right from the firebase documentation which makes me a bit hesitant to say it's quite useless. But your explanation seems to make perfect sense. I'll just wait a bit see if anyone has any other input but most likely this is the accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: @TheeBen have you got any other answers?

Comment: Sorry for the delay bro; had completely forgotten to accept your answer, thanks again

Comment: @TheeBen No problem at all. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to be able to do `obj.saveData().then(...)`, then you can return the inner promise like this:

```
 saveData : function() {          
      this.$.document.data = this.$.message.value; 
      // return this promise
      return this.$.document.save("/parent", "child").then(function() {
        console.log('sent the event!!!!!!');
        this.$.document.reset();
      }.bind(this));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm basically trying to understand what "Promise.resolve()" means here before anything else. It seems to me that the promise is gone through and then I am returning that phrase, what that means I'm not sure. and then where would I handle the error..

Comment: @TheeBen - `return Promise.resolve()` immediately returns a resolved promise that has zero connection with your asynchronous operations thus it doesn't do anything useful - it does not belong in this circumstance.  It's already resolved even before the async operations are done.  As my answer shows, you want to return the promise that is connected to your async operation.

Comment: it's interesting that it is in Firebase docs, not that they are errorproof ..  just makes me wonder ... thanks for your comment though

Comment: I'd have to see the context to understand what the docs were attempting to do.  I presume that context is different than exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TheeBen The doc link in your question doesn't show the code you've listed. Where exactly is the code from?

Comment: once I get a chance I will direct you to it